# Count words in text

Tags: c#, utf-8, counting

I need to count the *number of words* and the *number of unique words* from a UTF-8 text file, the text can contain any language. I tried the next option, but I get more words than in Word or online services.
I leave the text with no characters and then count the words by spaces, checking if the word is a word or a space. How i can get correct result?

```
string localText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fils[i], Encoding.UTF8);

localText = Regex.Replace(localText, @"[^\p{L}\d\s]", "");

var collection = Regex.Matches(localText, @"\b\w{1,}\b");

var wordsWithoutSpaces = collection
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Select(m => m.Value)
  .Where(word => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(word));

var uniqueMatches = collection
  .OfType<Match>()
  .Select(m => m.Value)
  .Distinct(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

`fils[i]` - folder of files

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we should *come to terms* with what a word is, if we agree that:

> Word is a not-empty sequence of chars which **must start** from a *letter* or *apostrophe* and **can contain** *letters*, *apostrophes* and *dashes* (minuses) `-`. The whole word **must be** between *word boundaries* (`_` is word boundary)

E.g:

```
'was           - 1 word 
Q.E.D.         - 3 words 
don't          - 1 word
forget-me-not  - 1 word
George W. Bush - 3 words
USA            - 1 word
PascalCase     - 1 word 
Snake_Case     - 2 words
R2D2           - 0 words
123            - 0 words
123e45         - 0 words
```

Then we can extract all the words as follow:

```
var words = Regex
  .Matches(localText, @"((?<=_)|\b)[\p{L}'][\p{L}'-]*(\b|(?=_))")
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Select(match => match.Value)
  .ToArray();
```

finally

```
int count = words.Length;
int uniqueCount = words.Distinct().Count();

// Case sensitive, i.e And != and
HashSet<string> uniqueWords = new HashSet<string>(words);
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9zbTTw)

Comment: Oh no, poor R2D2!